# Python: Easier way to change/edit items in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

```
strings = input("")
mylist = strings.split(" ")
print(mylist[0]+mylist[1],mylist[1]+mylist[2],mylist[2]+mylist[3],mylist[3]+mylist[4],mylist[4]+mylist[5],mylist[5]+mylist[6])
```

In the above code , if the user inputs ("a b c d e f g"), it prints out the desired result:
"ab bc cd de ef fg".
But,I would have to keep on changing the code for different input lengths. I tried using "for-in"  statement, but i get 'string index out of range', and other attempts using loops were futile. It's suppose to be space separated as shown.
BTW, this isn't a homework or assignment problem, just some revision for an upcoming test. Once i get the above method right i would be able to do the other similar problems. Please help. Python 3.3.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Print grouped by two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the full power of `print` function in Py3k:

```
strings = 'a b c d e f g'
mylist = strings.split()
for x, y in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]):
    print(x, y, sep='', end=' ') # ab bc cd de ef fg
```

**or** stick with simpler approach:

```
strings = 'a b c d e f g'
mylist = strings.split()
pairs = []

count = 0
for x in mylist:
    if count == len(mylist) - 1:
        break
    pairs += [mylist[count]+mylist[count+1]]
    count += 1

print(' '.join(pairs)) # ab bc cd de ef fg
```

Comment: We never use "zip" before so i don't think i should use it. Also, it prints the result such as "ab" and "bc" one below each other, instead of being in the same line.